# Cross Launch between 2 applications running in diff tomcat

Tags: java, tomcat, servlets

Here is my requirement.

I have 2 tomcats running 2 diff webapps, one webapp in each tomcat.
I launch the webapp1 (tomcat1) in the browser. Now i want to provide a link in the UI to launch webapp2(tomcat2) and reload the same browser page with webapp2 contents.

How can I do this?

Comment: but why do you need two instances of tomcat?

Comment: You mean you want to redirect from 1 tomcat to another?

Comment: they are 2 completely different application.

Comment: Yeah ...redirect from one tomcat to another